# match.group() not working when using python to find in array

Tags: python, json

What this script is doing is extracting the JS library that is being imported inside of tagcloud.js then checking it against test.json to see if it is okay to add it to the final array.

The problem is with the line `if imported.group(1) in allowedImports:` where even if imported.group(1) exists in test.json it doesn't come in to the if statement.

```
    with open('test.json') as allowedImportsArray:
        allowedImports = json.load(allowedImportsArray)

    apps = 'path-to-dir-where-tagcloud.js is'
    javaScriptImports = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(apps):
        for file in files:
            # print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
            if filepath.endswith(".js"):
                with open(filepath, "r") as myfile:
                    # grep for both types of require patterns
                    # require('copy-webpack-plugin')
                    # require([
                    #    'jquery',
                    # ],
                    pattern = re.compile(r'[require|define]\(\[/,/] | require\((.*)\)')
                    for line in myfile.readlines():
                        for matched_object in pattern.finditer(line):
                            # extract the strings and add them to javaScriptImports array
                            importedMatches = re.finditer(r"(?:\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)')", matched_object.group(1))
                            for imported in importedMatches:
                                if imported.group(1) in allowedImports:
                                    javaScriptImports.append(imported.group())
                            print(list(dict.fromkeys(javaScriptImports)))
```

tagcloud.js below:

```
define(function(require, module){
    var SimpleSplunkView = require('mvc/simpleview');
});
```

test.json below:

```
[
"mvc/simpleview"
]
```

Comment: When you have single quotes, the result will be in `.group(2)`, not `.group(1)`.

Comment: Why not the simpler `importedMatches = re.finditer(r"['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]`?  It would be fooled by mixed quotes, but you aren't likely to find that in a `require` statement.

Comment: The regex seems to work well when the require statement is quoted with single or double quotes and i updated to `.group(1)` which is working. Thank you